# Exporting/importing conda environment results in libraries with different source code

Tags: python, conda, peewee

Here are the steps followed on one computer to export a conda environment and to see the version and the 209th line of a module:

```
activate myenv
conda env export > p:\myenv.yml
python
import peewee
peewee.__version__
--> '2.8.5'
with open(peewee.__file__, 'r') as f:
  lines=f.read().split('\n')

lines[208]
--> '                if model._meta.depends_on:'
```

And here are the steps followed on another computer to import the same environment:

```
conda env create -f p:\myenv.yml
activate myenv
python
import peewee
peewee.__version__
--> '2.8.5'
with open(peewee.__file__, 'r') as f:
  lines=f.read().split('\n')

lines[208]
--> '        # Order models by name and table initially to guarantee total ordering.'
```

The version of peewee is the same on both the environments, but the 209th line (and many others) is different. Needless to say I can't run my app on the new computer.

How can the source files in two supposedly identical environments be different, even if they show the same version?

Here is the content of myenv.yml:

```
name: myenv
dependencies:
- cherrypy=3.8.0=py34_0
- jinja2=2.8=py34_1
- markupsafe=0.23=py34_2
- pillow=3.0.0=py34_0
- pip=9.0.1=py34_1
- pymongo=3.3.0=py34_0
- python=3.4.5=0
- pywin32=220=py34_1
- setuptools=27.2.0=py34_1
- vc=10=0
- vs2010_runtime=10.00.40219.1=2
- wheel=0.29.0=py34_0
- pip:
  - ezdxf==0.7.6
  - peewee==2.8.5
  - pyparsing==2.1.8
  - pypdf2==1.26.0
  - requests==2.13.0
```

Comment: I tend to use `conda list --explicit > requirements.txt` and `conda create --name XYZ --file requirements.txt` if I want to ensure that precisely the same version is downloaded from precisely the same repository. Could you try comparing the output of `conda list --explicit` on the two environments you've set up

Comment: @RussHyde Two problems with `conda list --explicit`: 1) packages installed with `pip` like `ezdxf`, `peewee`, etc. are not listed, and 2) it works on the new computer, but on the old one it says `conda-script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --explicit`

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that (though I don't use pip within conda).Is the order of your conda channels in .condarc identical between the two computers?

Comment: @RussHyde In the new computer I don't have `.condaarc`. I have `.conda` containing `environments.txt` with 4 lines, 2 of them identical. But `conda env list` shows 8 environments, the 3 in the file and 5 more. In the old computer (the server, that was my first anaconda installation and I may have made a mess) I can't find any `.conda` or `.condaarc`